# Adding px value to the return href + '#division'

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using this jQuery code which opens WordPress links at the "#separator". How could I add some additional pixel values to it? For example, I would need links to open at the #separator but with -50px.

```
jQuery("#navigation a").attr("href", function(i, href) {
return href + '#separator';
});
```

Comment: please provide your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
jQuery("#navigation a").attr("href", function(i, href) {
    return href + '#separator';
}).on('click', function(){
    var o = this.getAttribute('href');
    $(document).scrollTop($(o).offset().top - 50);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually harder than it looks. I think you should add a parameter to the url and then add some jquery code in the landing page, for example:

```
var offset=50;
jQuery("#navigation a").attr("href", function(i, href) {
    return href + '#separator' + '?offset=' + offset;
});
```

and then, on the other page:

```
var hash = $(location).attr('hash');
var positionTop = hash.offset().top;
var offset = parseInt(getParameterByName('offset'));
$('html, body').scrollTo(positionTop + offset)

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```